# Шифрование символов RSA, приведение unsigned char/unsigned int

Tags: c++, char, ascii

Есть код шифрования/дешифрования с помощью RSA:

```
void CRsaEncoding::Encode()
{
    cout << "Please wait... Key generation procces." << endl << endl;
    // Генерация двух чисел и выбор двух простых чисел.
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(nullptr)));
    int p = rand() % 100;
    int q = rand() % 100;
    int p_simple = sundaram(p);
    int q_simple = sundaram(q);
    //Находим число n.
    unsigned int n = p_simple*q_simple;
    //Генерация числа d и проверка его на взаимопростоту
    //с числом ((p_simple-1)*(q_simple-1)).
    int d = 0, d_simple = 0;
    while (d_simple != 1)
    {
        d = rand() % 100;
        d_simple = gcd(d, ((p_simple - 1)*(q_simple - 1)));
    }
    //Определение числа e, для которого является истинным
    //соотношение (e*d)%((p_simple-1)*(q_simple-1))=1.
    unsigned int e = 0, e_simple = 0;
    while (e_simple != 1)
    {
        e += 1;
        e_simple = (e*d) % ((p_simple - 1)*(q_simple - 1));
    }
    //Сгенерированные ключи.
    cout << '{' << setw(12) << e << ',' << setw(12) << n << '}' << " - Open key" << endl;
    cout << '{' << setw(12) << d << ',' << setw(12) << n << '}' << " - Secret key" << endl << endl;
    //Ввод шифруемых данных.
    const int MAX = 20;
    char *Text = new char[MAX];
    cout << "Please enter the Text. Use <Enter> button when done." << endl;
    cin.get(Text, MAX);
    //Массив для хранения шифротекста.
    unsigned int *CryptoText = new unsigned int[MAX];
    unsigned int *Tdecrypt = new unsigned int[MAX];
    //Получение из введённых данных десятичного кода ASCII и
    //дальнейшее его преобразование по формуле ci = (mj^e)%n.
    int b = 301;
    int c;
    cout << endl << setw(5) << "Text" << setw(6) << "ASCII"
        << setw(20) << "CryptoText/Block#" << setw(14)
        << "ASCIIdecrypt" << setw(14) << "Text decrypt" << endl
        << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
    {
        c = 1;
        unsigned int i = 0;
        int ASCIIcode = (static_cast<int>(Text[j])) + b;
        while (i<e)
        {
            c = c*ASCIIcode;
            c = c%n;
            i++;
        }
        CryptoText[j] = c;
        b += 1;
    }
    //Расшифровка полученного кода по формуле mi = (ci^d)%n
    //и перевод его в десятичный код ASCII.
    b = 301;
    int m;
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
    {
        m = 1;
        unsigned int i = 0;
        while (i<d)
        {
            m = m*CryptoText[j];
            m = m%n;
            i++;
        }
        m = m - b;
        Tdecrypt[j] = m;
        b += 1;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << Text[j] << setw(6) << static_cast<int>(Text[j]) << setw(20)
            << CryptoText[j] << setw(14) << Tdecrypt[j] << setw(14) << static_cast<char>(Tdecrypt[j]) << endl;
    }
    delete[] Text;
    delete[] CryptoText;
    delete[] Tdecrypt;
}
```

Я не могу понять и вычислить уже который час, почему b = 301, и что самое интересное, оно работает, и исключительно при значении 301. ПОЧЕМУ?
[image: При значении b=302]
[image: При значении b=301]

Comment: В следующий раз используйте отступы (или кнопку {} на выделенном коде), а не выделение одинарными кавычками.

Comment: @AivanF. недавно на ресурсе, не разобрался еще, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: При значениях отличных от 301 или вообще если убрать переменную "b" дешифрование символов происходит неадекватно, в консоли отображается что-то непонятное. Интересно также, каким образом получаются отрицательные значения в случае ввода кирилицы, и каким образом оно все-же умудряется дешифровать отрицательные значения (при том же b=301) обратно в кирилицу

Answer (score 1):

Просто автор алгоритма не захотел делать шифрование и дешифрование с помошью алгоритма возведения в степень по модулю (Это алгоритм который используется при  шифровании и дешифровании в описании алгоритма) и  обшелся таким способом.

```
long long modular_pow(long long base, unsigned long long exp, unsigned long long  modul)
{
    long long d = 1;
    unsigned long long  mask = 0x8000000000000000;
    long long modulus = modul;
    unsigned int shift = 63;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
    {
        d = (d*d) % modulus;
        if ((exp&mask) >> shift)
            d = (d*base) % modulus;
        mask >>= 1;
        --shift;
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Значения кириллических символов отрицательны в таблице символов -поэтому и  получаются отрицательные значения.

Comment: Хорошо, почему в таком случае именно 301? Если убрать инкремент при шифровании и декремент при дешифровании тех самых 301, то результат приведен выше. Если вместо 301 ввести какое-либо другое значение - результат тот же.

Comment: @Сергей я дал ответ выше.

Comment: Я все еще не совсем понял принцип выбора данного числа, а так как с C++ я буквально недавно начал ознакамливаться, то не могу вникнуть в ваш пример, в частности в строку 
 if ((exp&mask) >> shift)d = (d*base) % modulus;
Не могли бы вы , пожалуйста, объяснить подробнее?

Comment: Идея следующая: число преобразуется в двоичную  форму. В нашем случае число unsigned long long то есть 8 байт в байте 8 бит,  таким образом 8*8 =64- поэтому цикл на 64 операции.далее в алгоритме идет анализ каждого бита( биты могут быть или 0 или 1)((exp&mask) >> shift) -это анализ текущего бита.В условии можно написать так  ((exp&mask) >> shift)==1) если вам так понятнее.В зависимости от ветки условия выполняем те или иные действия.

Comment: @Cергей  посмотрите описание  RSA, а именно формулы для шифрования и дешифрования. После этого вам пригодится моя реализация алгоритмы возведения в степень по модулю. Однако, может быть одна проблема.В сигнатуре  и теле метода я использую long и unsiged long long. Вам это все стоит заменить на те типы которые будете использовать вы(int,  unsigned int и так далее) это связано с работой функции деления по модулю %, если оставить как у меня может не корректно работать

Comment: @Kiril21 Я уже посмотрел, и в принципе намерения автора и ваш алгоритм понял, но до сих пор не могу понять как получилось именно 301, можете мне вывести эту же цифру любым более-менее логичным образом? Стыдно даже за свою тугость.

Comment: @Kiril21 бинарные операции я в своё время прошляпил и никогда толком не использовал =(

Comment: @Сергей,цифру 301 не выведу. Так как  не автор я. могу лишь предположить что как -то связано это с таблицей символов. Приложу лишь ссылку на свою реализацию, если у вас возникнут вопросы:https://github.com/Kirill71/RSA-Criptography